# iOS SDKs: Renaming a lot of classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I'm developing an iOS SDK that integrates other SDKs (Facebook SDK 3.5, for example).
To prevent collisions and allow my customers to import those SDKs as well, I want to rename all of the classes/enums in my code (for example, rename FBSession to RDFBSession, etc).

Is there an easy way to do this instead of going class-by-class and using Xcode's rename feature?

Comment: Xcode has a Refactor function, which will make it easier.

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm aware of that, thing is, there are a lot of classes and other symbols to rename. It would still be a lengthy painful process.

Comment: You better get started then, else you'll never finish.  Source code is too complex that a one-click solution could exist to do what you want.  You'll have to do it yourself basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode also offers textual Search and Replace. This will be faster than individual refactors, but it is ultimately less automated. You can make the step by step refactoring faster by first minimizing the project to the relevant dependencies/sources (if possible).

However, renaming the declarations in a library will not alter the symbol names of its associated binary. If it is distributed with a binary, then renaming will just result in linker errors or (in some cases) runtime errors.

The best idea if you need to use a 3rd party library which your clients might also use is to simply inform them they need to link the library with their app, then publish the version(s) the current release supports so they know they have some extra testing if they go too far ahead with some libraries.

Comment: I've decided to go with the method described in the last paragraph. It just seems like the cleanest approach to this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Apple provide a command-line tool called [`tops(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tops.1.html) that is designed for scripting large-scale code refactoring (renaming C functions, Objective-C methods, classes, and other tokens):

```
 tops -verbose replace "FBSession" with "RDFBSession" Sources/*.[hm]
```

If you have a lot of replacements, you can put all of the `replace...` commands into a file that you pass with the `-scriptfile` option. The [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tops.1.html) has more information on the more complex commands/options (and examples).

Answer (score -1):

I think that a better approach than simply renaming your classes would be to download Facebook's open source code, rename the classes there and compile a new static library with a set of renamed header files. Then you can be sure that no collisions occur and that you're using symbols that you named yourself.

I must warn you though - working like this may make updating the SDK a nightmare regardless of how you tackle this specific issue.

Comment: This is a bad idea, as he may need to update the FB SDK in the future,. If so, he would have to go through the work of naming everything from FB again. Better to go through the hard work of renaming his classes. Sometimes the best approach is not easy.

Comment: If he renames his classes locally, he'll still need to do it all over again for each FB SDK update.